# Recovering private key when someone uses the same k twice in ECDSA signatures

Tags: ecdsa, recover-private-key

In this blog: https://web.archive.org/web/20160308014317/http://www.nilsschneider.net/2013/01/28/recovering-bitcoin-private-keys.html
the author showed a case that using same k twice will leak private key.

Many people know this method. But I find sometimes, the formula can not give the right answer(or I compute wrong).

Look at this, you can verify signatures by public key:

```
public_key = 02a50eb66887d03fe186b608f477d99bc7631c56e64bb3af7dc97e71b917c5b364
msghash1 = 01b125d18422cdfa7b153f5bcf5b01927cf59791d1d9810009c70cd37b14f4e6
msghash2 = 339ff7b1ced3a45c988b3e4e239ea745db3b2b3fda6208134691bd2e4a37d6e1
sig1 = 304402200861cce1da15fc2dd79f1164c4f7b3e6c1526e7e8d85716578689ca9a5dc349d02206cf26e2776f7c94cafcee05cc810471ddca16fa864d13d57bee1c06ce39a3188
sig2 = 304402200861cce1da15fc2dd79f1164c4f7b3e6c1526e7e8d85716578689ca9a5dc349d02204ba75bdda43b3aab84b895cfd9ef13a477182657faaf286a7b0d25f0cb9a7de2
```

So input data:

```
r=0861cce1da15fc2dd79f1164c4f7b3e6c1526e7e8d85716578689ca9a5dc349d
s1=6cf26e2776f7c94cafcee05cc810471ddca16fa864d13d57bee1c06ce39a3188
s2=4ba75bdda43b3aab84b895cfd9ef13a477182657faaf286a7b0d25f0cb9a7de2
z1=01b125d18422cdfa7b153f5bcf5b01927cf59791d1d9810009c70cd37b14f4e6
z2=339ff7b1ced3a45c988b3e4e239ea745db3b2b3fda6208134691bd2e4a37d6e1
```

I work out:

```
private key = eaa57720a5b012351d42b2d9ed6409af2b7cff11d2b8631684c1c97f49685fbb
public key = 04e0e81185567ea58fc7e7258aa4d5c3e201a8d4ce2810c1007d87727a67eeb9a8c2ba06935280209f8bf42fc7603b65095f036044c4124ddf7c6a250cb450e4c8
```

However, it's wrong.

I'm using this python code to compute:

```
# this function is from 
# https://github.com/warner/python-ecdsa/blob/master/ecdsa/numbertheory.py
def inverse_mod( a, m ):
    """Inverse of a mod m."""
    if a < 0 or m <= a: a = a % m
    # From Ferguson and Schneier, roughly:
    c, d = a, m
    uc, vc, ud, vd = 1, 0, 0, 1
    while c != 0:
        q, c, d = divmod( d, c ) + ( c, )
        uc, vc, ud, vd = ud - q*uc, vd - q*vc, uc, vc

    # At this point, d is the GCD, and ud*a+vd*m = d.
    # If d == 1, this means that ud is a inverse.
    assert d == 1
    if ud > 0: return ud
    else: return ud + m


def derivate_privkey(p, r, s1, s2, hash1, hash2):
    z = hash1 - hash2
    s = s1 - s2
    r_inv = inverse_mod(r, p)
    s_inv = inverse_mod(s, p)
    k = (z * s_inv) % p
    d = (r_inv * (s1 * k - hash1)) % p
    return d, k


p  = 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFEBAAEDCE6AF48A03BBFD25E8CD0364141

# this case is right
public_key=0x04dbd0c61532279cf72981c3584fc32216e0127699635c2789f549e0730c059b81ae133016a69c21e23f1859a95f06d52b7bf149a8f2fe4e8535c8a829b449c5ff
r =0xd47ce4c025c35ec440bc81d99834a624875161a26bf56ef7fdc0f5d52f843ad1
s1=0x44e1ff2dfd8102cf7a47c21d5c9fd5701610d04953c6836596b4fe9dd2f53e3e
s2=0x9a5f1c75e461d7ceb1cf3cab9013eb2dc85b6d0da8c3c6e27e3a5a5b3faa5bab
z1=0xc0e2d0a89a348de88fda08211c70d1d7e52ccef2eb9459911bf977d587784c6e
z2=0x17b0f41c8c337ac1e18c98759e83a8cccbc368dd9d89e5f03cb633c265fd0ddc
print "private:%x\n random:%x" % derivate_privkey(p,r,s1,s2,z1,z2)
print

# this case can be wrong
public_key=0x02a50eb66887d03fe186b608f477d99bc7631c56e64bb3af7dc97e71b917c5b364
r =0x0861cce1da15fc2dd79f1164c4f7b3e6c1526e7e8d85716578689ca9a5dc349d
s1=0x6cf26e2776f7c94cafcee05cc810471ddca16fa864d13d57bee1c06ce39a3188
s2=0x4ba75bdda43b3aab84b895cfd9ef13a477182657faaf286a7b0d25f0cb9a7de2
z1=0x01b125d18422cdfa7b153f5bcf5b01927cf59791d1d9810009c70cd37b14f4e6
z2=0x339ff7b1ced3a45c988b3e4e239ea745db3b2b3fda6208134691bd2e4a37d6e1

print "private:%x\n random:%x" % derivate_privkey(p,r,s1,s2,z1,z2)
```

In fact, there have another one met this problem:

https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/16615/ecdsa-how-to-retrieve-a-non-random-k

But he didn't gave more infomation, maybe he figured it out.

I have not found more people complaining about it, so, it's likely my fault somehow.

Can you point out my error? or just point out the right way? Thank you.

Comment: It seems like the second public key is compressed - maybe that's the issue?

Comment: no, signature has nothing to do with public key compressed or not. because verifing signature always using uncompressed public key. and the formula doesn't need public key.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here is a fun thing about ECDSA signatures: you can always replace `s` with `-s` (mod N) and the signature is still valid.  So when you are deducing the `k` value, it is possible that someone else flipped the sign of `s` and you will have to undo it.  So, you have to make a list of candidates for `k` (kandidates?) and then select whichever one actually works.  A good list of k candidates would be:

- (z1 - z2) / (s1 - s2)
- (z1 - z2) / (s1 + s2)
- (z1 - z2) / (-s1 - s2)
- (z1 - z2) / (-s1 + s2)

I like to use the [Ruby ECDSA gem](https://github.com/DavidEGrayson/ruby_ecdsa) to play around with this kind of stuff.  Here is the code I wrote which successfully finds the private key for the first input data you gave:

```
require 'ecdsa'

public_key_hex = '02a50eb66887d03fe186b608f477d99bc7631c56e64bb3af7dc97e71b917c5b364'
msghash1_hex = '01b125d18422cdfa7b153f5bcf5b01927cf59791d1d9810009c70cd37b14f4e6'
msghash2_hex = '339ff7b1ced3a45c988b3e4e239ea745db3b2b3fda6208134691bd2e4a37d6e1'
sig1_hex = '304402200861cce1da15fc2dd79f1164c4f7b3e6c1526e7e8d85716578689ca9a5dc349d02206cf26e2776f7c94cafcee05cc810471ddca16fa864d13d57bee1c06ce39a3188'
sig2_hex = '304402200861cce1da15fc2dd79f1164c4f7b3e6c1526e7e8d85716578689ca9a5dc349d02204ba75bdda43b3aab84b895cfd9ef13a477182657faaf286a7b0d25f0cb9a7de2'

group = ECDSA::Group::Secp256k1

def hex_to_binary(str)
  str.scan(/../).map(&:hex).pack('C*')
end

public_key_str = hex_to_binary(public_key_hex)
public_key = ECDSA::Format::PointOctetString.decode(public_key_str, group)

puts 'public key x: %#x' % public_key.x
puts 'public key y: %#x' % public_key.y

msghash1 = hex_to_binary(msghash1_hex)
msghash2 = hex_to_binary(msghash2_hex)
sig1 = ECDSA::Format::SignatureDerString.decode(hex_to_binary(sig1_hex))
sig2 = ECDSA::Format::SignatureDerString.decode(hex_to_binary(sig2_hex))

raise 'R values are not the same' if sig1.r != sig2.r

r = sig1.r
puts 'sig r: %#x' % r
puts 'sig1 s: %#x' % sig1.s
puts 'sig2 s: %#x' % sig2.s

sig1_valid = ECDSA.valid_signature?(public_key, msghash1, sig1)
sig2_valid = ECDSA.valid_signature?(public_key, msghash2, sig2)
puts "sig1 valid: #{sig1_valid}"
puts "sig2 valid: #{sig2_valid}"

# Step 1: k = (z1 - z2)/(s1 - s2)
field = ECDSA::PrimeField.new(group.order)
z1 = ECDSA::Format::IntegerOctetString.decode(msghash1)
z2 = ECDSA::Format::IntegerOctetString.decode(msghash2)

k_candidates = [
  field.mod((z1 - z2) * field.inverse(sig1.s - sig2.s)),
  field.mod((z1 - z2) * field.inverse(sig1.s + sig2.s)),
  field.mod((z1 - z2) * field.inverse(-sig1.s - sig2.s)),
  field.mod((z1 - z2) * field.inverse(-sig1.s + sig2.s)),
]

private_key = nil
k_candidates.each do |k|
  next unless group.new_point(k).x == r
  private_key_maybe = field.mod(field.mod(sig1.s * k - z1) * field.inverse(r))
  if public_key == group.new_point(private_key_maybe)
    private_key = private_key_maybe
  end
end

puts 'private key: %#x' % private_key
```

The output of the program is:

```
public key x: 0xa50eb66887d03fe186b608f477d99bc7631c56e64bb3af7dc97e71b917c5b364
public key y: 0x7954da3444d33b8d1f90a0d7168b2f158a2c96db46733286619fccaafbaca6bc
sig r: 0x861cce1da15fc2dd79f1164c4f7b3e6c1526e7e8d85716578689ca9a5dc349d
sig1 s: 0x6cf26e2776f7c94cafcee05cc810471ddca16fa864d13d57bee1c06ce39a3188
sig2 s: 0x4ba75bdda43b3aab84b895cfd9ef13a477182657faaf286a7b0d25f0cb9a7de2
sig1 valid: true
sig2 valid: true
private key: 0xe773cf35fce567d0622203c28f67478a3361bae7e6eb4366b50e1d27eb1ed82e
```

Comment: very good! I find the first two candidates are enough, last two are the same thing.

Comment: I considered that, but actually you do need all 4 candidates.  Only one of the 4 produces the right public key in the end.  The formula (s*k-z)/r is affected by the sign of k.

Comment: Adding to [David Grayson's](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/35850/38899) excellent answer the [python ecdsa-private-key-recovery library](https://github.com/tintinweb/ecdsa-private-key-recovery) is an easy to use wrapper for ecdsa/dsa signatures that is capable of recovering the private key from signatures sharing the same k/r. Once recovered you'll get ready to use private key populated `Cryptodome/PyCrypto/ecdsa` objects. The lib can easily be used to recover private keys from vulnerable btc transactions.

Answer (score 1):

```
r =0x0861cce1da15fc2dd79f1164c4f7b3e6c1526e7e8d85716578689ca9a5dc349d  
s1=0x6cf26e2776f7c94cafcee05cc810471ddca16fa864d13d57bee1c06ce39a3188  
s2=0x4ba75bdda43b3aab84b895cfd9ef13a477182657faaf286a7b0d25f0cb9a7de2  
z1=0x01b125d18422cdfa7b153f5bcf5b01927cf59791d1d9810009c70cd37b14f4e6  
z2=0x339ff7b1ced3a45c988b3e4e239ea745db3b2b3fda6208134691bd2e4a37d6e1  


h1 = r*(s1-s2)  
p1 = (z1*s2) - (z2*s1)  

h1 = r*(s1+s2)  
p1 = (z1*s2) - (z2*s1)  

h1 = r*(-s1-s2)  
p1 = (z1*s2) - (z2*s1)  

h1 = r*(-s1+s2)  
p1 = (z1*s2) - (z2*s1)  

h1 = r*(s1-s2)  
p1 = (z1*s2) + (z2*s1)  

h1 = r*(s1+s2)  
p1 = (z1*s2) + (z2*s1)  

h1 = r*(-s1+s2)  
p1 = (z1*s2) + (z2*s1)  

h1 = r*(-s1-s2)  
p1 = (z1*s2) + (z2*s1)  
print(hex((p1 *inverse_mod(h1, p)) % p))
```

output:

```
0xe773cf35fce567d0622203c28f67478a3361bae7e6eb4366b50e1d27eb1ed82e
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on OP's existing formula and David Grayson's answer above, here is a more modern (Python 3.8+) solution that works for both Bitcoin and Ethereum accounts, for those curious:

```
r = 0x...
s1 = 0x...
s2 = 0x...
# For Ethereum msg hash, feel free to use this excellent online toolkit: https://toolkit.abdk.consulting/ethereum#recover-address
z1 = 0x...
z2 = 0x...

# This function is from
# https://github.com/tlsfuzzer/python-ecdsa/blob/master/src/ecdsa/numbertheory.py
def inverse_mod(a, m):
    """Inverse of a mod m."""
    if a == 0:  # pragma: no branch
        return 0
    return pow(a, -1, m)

# Magic: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Secp256k1
p = 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFEBAAEDCE6AF48A03BBFD25E8CD0364141

for (i, j) in [(1,1),(1,-1),(-1,1),(-1,-1)]:
    z = z1 - z2
    s = s1*i + s2*j
    r_inv = inverse_mod(r, p)
    s_inv = inverse_mod(s, p)
    k = (z * s_inv) % p
    d = (r_inv * (s1 * k - z1)) % p
    print(f"Private key: {hex(d)}, {hex(k)}")
```