# What happens if I use same k twice in DSA algorithm?

Tags: bitcoin-core, signature, algorithms

To sign a message , we choose nonce k but what happens if we use same k twice to sign a message using DSA algorithm?

Answer (score 3):

If you sign two messages using the same nonce, then it is possible for someone to derive your private key. See [How do you derive the private key from two signatures that share the same k value?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/73622/how-do-you-derive-the-private-key-from-two-signatures-that-share-the-same-k-valu)