# Conditions for recovering a p2pkh bitcoin private key

Tags: blockchain, private-key

Apart from Re-using same R value, What are the necessarily ecdsa values needed or method to recover the private key of a p2pkh address.

When same address is reused numerous times to receive bitcoin what threat does it pose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What are the necessarily ecdsa values needed to recover the private key of a p2pkh address.

A key is recoverable if two signatures are created with the [same R value](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/73622/7272).

> When same address is reused numerous times to receive bitcoin what threat does it pose?

It leads to some loss of privacy, allowing different payments to be linked together.

Comment: Reusing addresses might also put you in a predicament where you are unaware of which customer paid for what service, especially if they are priced the same.

Comment: Is that the only conditions for recovering p2pkh private key? Apart from reused R values

Comment: It's not really relevant that it is a p2pkh key - Two signatures with the same value are all you need to recover an ECDSA private key. The key can also be "recovered" if it was created with bad entropy, such as via a brainwalle.