# How to find Reused R values

Tags: transactions, blockchain, hash, signature, ecdsa

I use software from  `https://github.com/ca333/rng-scanner` , I try to find r that is reused. from the software I found results

```
Bitcoin Address : 1GQdrgqAbkeEPUef1UpiTc4X1mUHMcyuGW
In Input NR : 141 ~ 220020a271a0897f1b7a7f0db9acb517ae2b6d53dda3833808d02c6a1cc21dc1a68680
Resued R-Value : a0897f1b7a7f0db9acb517ae2b6d53dda3833808d02c6a1cc21dc1a68680
```

How do I find the s and z of the reused r value?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Recovering private key when someone uses the same k twice in ECDSA signatures](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/35848/recovering-private-key-when-someone-uses-the-same-k-twice-in-ecdsa-signatures) or this: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/73622/how-do-you-derive-the-private-key-from-two-signatures-that-share-the-same-k-valu

Answer (score 1):

The one of the best way (I do it by that way) to find reused **R** values is to parse the raw blockchain database with my [blockchain parser](https://github.com/ragestack/blockchain-parser) with extracting only **Input script** and **TX hash** values and then cut off from script strings all except **R** value. So you get all **R** values ever generated. Then you can check those data for reusing **R** and easily find those TX's full data using it's hash.

This is the universal automated method for making such research for blockchain. I think this way is not the way like *getreusedr > result.txt* but I think it also can help you very much.