# RSZ value with witness data

Tags: private-key, hash, development

Have anyone got a script on how to find the RSZ value of a bitcoin transaction with witness data, scanned just  by inputting the hashes?

Will you please share your code?

Or at least, point me to the right direction...

Thank you...

Comment: Hi Roy, we do get a lot of people asking about r, s, and z values of transactions, but I'm wholly confused by the line of inquiry. Could you perhaps enlighten me what that sort of data is useful for or why people might be interested in it?

Comment: Hi @Murch.. Some of us do work as a Network Penetration Tester. In order for us to deliver the weaknesses, we need to find the RSZ values. Then only people like you can deliver a more secure solutions. Would u be able to help me out on the script?

Comment: Thanks, it's not clear to me what sort of weaknesses you're looking for, but I don't think you're onto something if you're spending time trying to break ECDSA.

Comment: I broke the ECDSA, got the private keys without the witness script before and send the codes to be analyse. Its OK. I'm just wondering whether there are any scripts in the wind right now. Saves me a lot of time. But I guess I will have to code it myself with witness in mind. Cheers.

Comment: Do you mean that you managed to extract a private key, because someone reused a nonce with the same key but on different transactions?

Comment: hey Murch. sorry for the late reply. this method was very well known then. https://hackernoon.com/hacking-a-bitcoin-wallet-642u36sa

Comment: The problem is these days, there is this witness input thats part of the whole sigscript. hence, making all penetration testing programs obsolete if they dont factor in the witness data. do email me if u interested to find out more. im only here because i was looking for any scripts that had alrdy been wrote. thanks man. you may clone this program right here to do get the RSZ breakdown..but with witness...this program dont work. https://github.com/iceland2k14/rsz

Comment: I mean, of course… Reusing a nonce with the same key but different messages leads to a simple set of equations that can be solved for the private key. https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/110814/5406. That's not "breaking ECDSA" though, that's finding people that improperly use ECDSA and stealing their funds.

Comment: https://github.com/TheBes3rdsGroup/bitcoinwalletscanner ..here is to check for wallets that has reuse R value.

Comment: well yes. thats how some people does it to steal funds. thats my work though. i report this new techniques ..or if i am able to create a new technique, my company shout them out .

Comment: Thanks for explaining. I must admit I'd be surprised if you find any cases still.

Comment: well, im from Singapore. about a month ago we had a case in a neighboring country. someone manage to crack it with witness as part of the whole script. the dude is sure not talking how he did it. hence, why im here and everywhere. nice talking to you Murch.